# How do we visit DisabledTextTrivia in Roslyn API?

Tags: c#, roslyn

We have a lot of conditional Silverlight code, which is now garbage.

I would like to write a tool to remove all this code using `CSharpSyntaxRewriter`. However, I do not know how to write it. When I do not specify the SILVERLIGHT define constant in the parse options, the visitor skips over all the `DisabledTextTrivia` instances, some of which I want to delete (because not all of them are disabled due to SILVERLIGHT being undefined).

I think I have to parse with SILVERLIGHT enabled and check every `#if` and `#elif` directive whether the visited code is enabled due to SILVERLIGHT or some other condition.

In short it looks ugly.

Is there anything I am missing? Some kind of a built-in goody?